# How to port from JS to REACT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have the following function which sets the CSS property of an HTML element. I'm trying to use the same in REACT and it is not working due to obvious reasons.

Any idea on how I can achieve the same result??

```
$(function fn1() {
  var myIndex = 0;
  carousel();

   function carousel() {
      var i;
      var totalElements = document.getElementsByClassName("imgClass");
      for (i = 0; i < totalElements.length; i++) 
       {
       totalElements[i].style.display = "none";
       }

     myIndex++;
     if (myIndex > totalElements.length) 
     {
     myIndex = 1;
     }

    totalElements[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
 }
});
```

REACT CODE:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ImageSlide from "./ImageSlide";
const axios = require("axios");
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:1337";
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
Authorization:
"bearer " +
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YjZmOTk4ODU2YjBjOTA1NTg2OTI0ZWIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzQwNDEyNjQsImV4cCI6MTUzNjYzMzI2NH0.nPEcbkoJ4wcbwi_CEX4hVKXB0PJnUtt3VuHcBljbF2s"
};
// const absolutePath = "../../strapui/app/public";

export class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { imageData: null };
}

componentDidMount() {
  let url = "http://localhost:1337/product";

  axios
  .get(url)
  .then(response => {
  // handle success
  const imageData = response.data;
  imageData && this.setState({ imageData });
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // handle error
  console.log(error);
  });
}

render() {
  const images = require.context(
  "../../strapui/app/public/uploads",
  true,
  /\.jpg$/
  );
  const keys = images.keys();
  const svgsArray = keys.map(key => images(key));
  const imageData = this.state.imageData;

  if (imageData === null) return null;
  return (
   <div className="container">
    <div className="slideshowContainer">
     <div className="colItemLeft">
      <a href="/product?prod=cust" id="dh">
       <div className="dhOverlay">
        <ImageSlide
         styles="imgClass"
         imagePath={imageData[0].image}
         svgsArray={svgsArray}
        />
       <div className="overlayDH">
        <img
         src={require("./assets/folder1/0.png?")}
         alt=""
        />
       </div>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Container;
```

I'm just a beginner in REACT a friend of mine had helped me a bit with the coding for REACT I've updated the question with REACT code where I want the JS function mentioned in the post to change the CSS property. The images are retrieved from the database inside the function

Comment: Show what you have tried in React

Comment: @Justinas totalElements[i].style is not getting recognised by REACT it says "CAnt read propery style of undefined"

Comment: @DamianPeralta I took all my js and css files ran `npm run build` took the `bundle.js` and used it in react. Basically this function takes all the elements with classname `imgClass` and changes the css propery of display in a loop. There by creating a slideshow

Comment: @charlietfl `totalElements ` is scoped inside `carousel()` function and it is called within that scope.

Comment: So it means your `totalElements` is NULL. It's JS, React does not prevent you from using plain JS. Make sure you have elements with class `imgClass`

Comment: Sorry...your inconsistent formatting made it har to read and I was incorrect

Comment: @Justinas I did console log. I am getting a `HTMLCollection` with 6 entries for `totalElements` but while doing `console.log(totalElements.lenght)` it returns 0

Comment: I highly recommend reading *and following along* with the official [Intro to React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). It not only teaches you about specific React functionality and the proper 'React way' of programming, but also *why* things work that way.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to manipulate the DOM without interfere with react rendering you have to use shouldComponentUpdate() (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and return true inside the method.
Second, set refs to your elements (https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs).
Third, on componentWillUnmount (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) remove your listeners, setInterval, setTimeout.

Comment: Hi, I'm just a beginner in REACT a friend of mine had helped me a bit with the coding for REACT I've updated the question with REACT code where I want the JS function mentioned in the post to change the css property. The images are retrieved from the database inside the function `<ImageSlide>`